# unable to find string using indexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the function to set the https to the url passed in input.

```
setHttps(a) {
    if (a.indexOf('http://') > 0){
            a.replace('http', 'https')
            console.log('priting url if...... ', a);
        } else if(a.indexOf('https://') == -1 && a.indexOf('http://') == -1) {
            a = a.replace (/^/,'https://');
            console.log("printing url else........ ", a);
        } 
    return a;
}
```

When I pass the following:

1. www.example.com --> converts to ---> https://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com --> doesn't get converted to ---> https://www.example.com

Why? It looks like `indexOf('http://')` is unable to find `http://` in the string.

Comment: `a.indexOf('http://') > -1`

Comment: May restrict the replacement to the start of the url, e. g. http://google.com/search?q=site:http://test.com+test

Answer (score 4):

There are atleast 2 issues in your code:

```
a.indexOf('http://') > 0    // should be >= 0
a.replace('http', 'https')  // replace returns a String
```

Try the following:

```
setHttps(a) {
var a = self.previewUrl.value;
if (a.indexOf('http://') >= 0){
        a = a.replace('http', 'https')
        console.log('priting url if...... ', a);
    } else if(a.indexOf('https://') == -1 && a.indexOf('http://') == -1) {
        a = a.replace (/^/,'https://');
        console.log("printing url else........ ", a);
    } 
return a;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the variable with returned value. Although use `http://` instead of `http` to avoid matching `http` in `https` and index starts from `0` so update condition based on that.

```
if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1){
    a = a.replace('http://', 'https://')
}
```

---

**UPDATE :** In the `else if` condition `a.indexOf('http://') == -1` is not necessary since it already checked in first `if`.

```
setHttps(a) {
    if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1){
            a= a.replace('http://', 'https://')
            console.log('priting url if...... ', a);
        } else if(a.indexOf('https://') == -1) {
            a = a.replace (/^/,'https://');
            // or simply concat
            // a = 'https://' + a;
            console.log("printing url else........ ", a);
        } 
    return a;
}
```

Comment: if the variable contains https in it then wont  it become httpss

Comment: @naresh would have been better if it was mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Read about [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
>   can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

**Update:**

```
if(a.indexOf('http://') > -1){
   a = a.replace("http", "https");
}else if(a.indexOf('https') === -1){
   a = "https://" + a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript grammar "-1" is usually used as sentinel value, and it comes from C.

`String.prototype.indexOf` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

So you'll probably want to do something like :

```
setHttps(a) {
    var a = self.previewUrl.value;
    if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1){
            a.replace('http', 'https')
            console.log('priting url if...... ', a);
        } else if(a.indexOf('https://') == -1 && a.indexOf('http://') == -1) {
            a = a.replace (/^/,'https://');
            console.log("printing url else........ ", a);
        } 
    return a;
}
```

Comment: a = a.replace('http', 'https')

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code

```
setHttps(a) {
    if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1){
            a.replace('http', 'https')
            console.log('priting url if...... ', a);
        } else if(a.indexOf('https://') == -1 && a.indexOf('http://') == -1) {
            a = a.replace (/^/,'https://');
            console.log("printing url else........ ", a);
        } 
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (a.indexOf('http://') > 0)
```

to

```
if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1)
```

`"http://www.example.com".indexOf('http://')` outputs 0 as 'http://' is at that index in the provided URL.

Also, you need to assign the a.replace's output back to a, so the final code would look like this:

```
function setHttps(a) {
    if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1){
            a = a.replace('http', 'https');
            console.log('priting url if...... ', a);
        } else if(a.indexOf('https://') == -1 && a.indexOf('http://') == -1) {
            a = a.replace (/^/,'https://');
            console.log("printing url else........ ", a);
        } 
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this

`if (a.indexOf('http://') > 0)`

to

`if (a.indexOf('http://') > -1)`

It is because, `indexOf()` returns the index of the first occurrence of the string. Here in your case, the first occurrence of `http://` is 0. 
But, your condition is true if `indexOf() > 0`. So you need to change the condition so that it would work for `0` also.